# Changing the title bar's color

Tags: python, pyqt, themes, python-3.4, pyqt5

I've been working on an interface for a program:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ews9fm6mo33ujoh/Screenshot%202015-03-22%2010.46.35.png?dl=0

The issue with it is that the title bar does not have the same color as the rest of the window, and is instead the normal color. I'm trying to base this program's look off of the new Photoshop, and I know that [it can change the title bar color.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7mnyqzqw220r6w/Screenshot%202015-03-22%2010.48.44.png?dl=0)

My program is written with Python 3.4 and PyQt5 + Qt5.4, but I'd be happy to use more/different modules as well to fix this. 

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of (and most likely the easiest): Make your own titlebar.

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377914/pyqt-customize-title-bar-and-window). You will need to emulate the look and feel of the title bar, but Qt has all of the functions to hide and close your GUI, so it shouldn't be too hard. Then you can customize it with qss styling.

OS makers, especially Apple, like to keep their color schemes very similar, that is why it is a 'hack' when people install [custom windows themes](http://www.howtogeek.com/168270/how-to-install-custom-themes-and-visual-styles-in-windows/). Microsoft doesn't want people changing things up too much.

#### Pros:

-Cross Platform code (you may want to load different style sheets based on os)
-No new libraries
-Completely customizable
-Unified look on all platforms (if you use one style sheet)

#### Cons:

-Need to change style sheets per platform (optional)