# Setting Custom Color for Title Bar

Tags: python, titlebar, pyside2

Ive been learning to build a GUI in Python recently and have had trouble figuring out one key feature I am looking for on my GUI: To colorize the titlebar.

Im mostly working in QtDesigner stylesheets but have no issue typing out code in the .py if I need to.

Ive had issues finding relevant examples in PySide2 as opposed to PyQt5, I prefer to use the Qt Team official modules(PySide2) if possible. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: It's not possible to do this, because the title-bar is provided by the window-manager and qt has no control over it. If you really want this, you will have to [implement a custom title-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9377914/984421) yourself.