# Qt Designer and Frameless Window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5

I am currently creating a GUI for an application and I want to make it frameless and add the minimize and close buttons myself. What I want to achieve can be seen in this answer:

[The window structure I want to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044028/10298597)

Since the GUI structure that I have in mind is really complex I really need that I have to use Qt Designer. Is there a way to achieve what is done in the answer above in the Qt Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to create your application window as usual in Qt Designer, load the .ui file in the python via `uic.loadUi` and add it to the layout of `box.contentWidget()` instead of the `edit` in the linked example.